# api to connect to conmanclient2/cmaccept

Tags: windows-ce, remote-debugging

I'm writing programs in C# & C++ that run on a custom Windows CE 5 and 6 device.  I have followed the instructions on how to connect to a CE device on Microsoft's site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708(v=vs.80).aspx), and things work fine with DevStudio and with the remote tools.

I am dissatisfied with the remote tools, however.  So I would like to write some better ones.  For sample, a command-line tool to copy *.dll to a directory on the device, which doesn't say "are you sure you want to overwrite that file?" for each one.

Does anyone know what protocol / API one uses to connect to the device using TCP/IP, here?  And/or can point me to a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CoreCon APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384093%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) provide a mechanism to do this.  The [VSD team blogged a 5-part example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/) of creating your own file viewer using the APIs some time back.